# v7 SearchView android

Tags: android

How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) which is not included in toolbar?

I want to filter the results in my recycler adapter using names which i am getting from api in a model.
I have set the recyclerview inside a fragment.

Comment: have you implemented your adapter with Filterable interface?

Comment: no. i have just set a searchview inside my activity above recyclerview. i do not know how to filter the results in recyclerview using that searchview

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) `Filterable` adapter and override its `matches()` method

Comment: please give an example @pskink

Comment: `class MyAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<MyPOJOClass, MyAdapter.ViewHolder {...`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it by searchview or edit text

for search view

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
      filter(s.toString(),getCustomDeviceCheckItemsList());
        return true;
    }
});



    private void filter(String text,ArrayList<CustomCheckItem> names) {
        //new array list that will hold the filtered data
        ArrayList<CustomCheckItem> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

        //looping through existing elements
        for (CustomCheckItem s : names) {

            //if the existing elements contains the search input

            if (s.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {

                //adding the element to filtered list
                filterdNames.add(s);
            }
        }

        //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
        childAdapter.filterList(filterdNames);
    }
```

and in adapter you have to write

```
   public void filterList(ArrayList<CustomItem> filterdNames) {
        this.list = filterdNames;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and if you want to do it by edit text then

```
  search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        filter(s.toString(),getCustomDeviceCheckItemsList());

            }
        });
```